# Why are dangling references allowed?

Tags: c++, reference

The draft C++ standard states

> The storage duration categories apply to references as well. The
>   lifetime of a reference is its storage duration.

And then

> A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after
>   initialization. Note that initialization of a reference is treated
>   very differently from assignment to it. Argument passing (5.2.2) and
>   function value return (6.6.3) are initializations.

So unlike pointers, which can be made to point to different memory, the same cannot be said for a reference. Why is it then that references have their own lifetime?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. "Why are dangling references allowed?" seems like a different question to "Why do references have lifetime?"  .

Comment: All variables have to have lifetime by definition, and references are variables.

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed to destroy an object that is referred to some reference, and to construct (e.g. by placement-new) another object in its storage location. The original reference becomes valid once again, as long as certain requirements are met.

To quote `3.8[basic.life]/7`

> 7 If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage
>   which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is
>   created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a
>   pointer that pointed to the original object, **a reference that
>   referred to the original object**, or the name of the original object
>   will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of
>   the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object,
>   if:

Comment: If anyone ever encounters a situation where this behaviour would be useful to them, shouldn't they just use pointers instead of references? That would signal the intent way better right? I don't see why the language has to overload the simplicity of references with this bloated nonsense.

Comment: @NikTedig no. it is probably impossible to make pointers recover after object replacement, but not references, and it makes no difference either way.

Comment: How is it impossible? The quote in the post refers to pointers as well as references. Even though it makes no difference, wouldn't it be beneficial to keep references simple instead of adding needless complexity to them, given that the same can be accomplished with a pointer? You might ask, why have references at all then, since you can do everything with pointers? Well, refs are useful when refs make sense. If a ref is alive longer than it's object, it doesn't make sense. A pointer would make more sense, given that it's more independent by definition.